# Is there a simpler way to find $E[X]$ than integrating joint distribution $ f_{x,y}(X,Y) = \frac1{2\pi} \exp[-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+4y^2-3xy+3y-2x+1)] $

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, density-function

In my textbook, it asks us to find E[X], E[Y], Var[X], Var[Y] and Cov(X,Y) of the following jointly Gaussian random variable:

$$ f_{x,y}(X,Y) = \frac1{2\pi} \exp\Bigg\{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+4y^2-3xy+3y-2x+1)\Bigg\}
$$

I've spent an unacceptable amount of time finding the marginal pdf of x via integration:

$$f_x(X) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Bigg\{ -\frac{41}{64} \big(x-1 \big)^2 \Bigg\}$$

and finding $E[X]$ by solving $\int_x xf_x(X) dx$ seems like an insane amount of work on top of what I've already done for just the solution to the first subquestion.

Am I missing something? Is there a simpler way of finding these things, or is my textbook just especially sadistic?

Comment: you could find out that the marginal distribution is a normal distribution with parameters $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and then see what the mean and variance are that way.

Comment: Then, because $f_x(X) = \frac{e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$, is it true that $\mu = 41$ and $\sigma^2=64$ ?

Comment: $\mu = 1$, $\sigma^2 = \frac{32}{41}$.

Comment: I got all the answers within 90 seconds using *Mathematica*.  Why do you folks persist in performing integrations by hand?  You don't multiply large numbers by hand... or invert matrices... or....

Comment: Your "distribution" isn't normalized:  $\int\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{y = -\infty}^{\infty} f_{x,y}(X,Y)\ dx\ dy = \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}$.

Comment: Please improve your question. See the comment of David G. Stork.

Comment: Let $-Q(x, y)/2$ be the exponent. The expectations are $\mu_1, \mu_2$ s.t. $(x, y) = (u, v) + (\mu_1, \mu_2)$ gives $Q = a u^2 + 2 b u v + c v^2$. The covariance matrix is
$$\Sigma = \begin {pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end {pmatrix}^{-1}.$$
The normalization constant is $1/(2 \pi \sqrt {\det \Sigma})$.

Comment: @callculus I double-checked: this is exactly how the question is written in my textbook. This being the case, I don't suppose I can just normalize it by throwing a $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$ in front of the equation, can I? I imagine it's just a typo and the question is unsolvable in a meaningful way as is.

Comment: @Zaya Yes you can and you must to normalize it. You cannot leave it as it is. But when you normalize it you should write it in the style of a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to find the pdf $f(x)$ without resorting to integration, instead, by just comparing the standard joint pdf,

$$\frac1{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} 
\exp\left[-\frac1{2(1-\rho^2)} \left( 
\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} + \frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}  
- \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}  \right) \right]$$

with the given pdf of the form

$$\frac1{2\pi A} e^{-\left(
ax^2+by^2 + c xy + dx+ ey +g \right)}$$

Note $\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}=A$. Then, we obtain $\rho$ from matching the coefficient $c$,
$$\frac{\rho}{A\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} = - c$$

Next, with known $\rho$, obtain $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ from

$$a = \frac1{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma_x^2},\>\>\>\>\>
b = \frac1{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma_y^2}$$

In the end, obtain $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ from matching the coefficients $d$ and $e$. Thus, from the deduced $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$, the pdf of $x$ is

$$f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_x}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} }$$

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely the sort of thing I was hoping I overlooked. I'll comment with the solution I find via this method when I get a chance

Comment: @Zaya - you're welcome. To apply, make sure you have a normalized joint pdf. The one you have in the post does not seem so.